# execute buffer content in current shell upon exec ssh

Tags: perl, shell, exec, stdin

My perl code does this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
sleep 2;
exec 'ssh', '-o', "ConnectTimeout=10", "newhost", "sleep 3;pwd";
```

the problem is when sleep is executing what ever I type on the terminal (during execution)
disappears to non interactive shell in newhost.

```
eg:
user@a02$perl test.pl
ls
user@a02$ #ls is not executed
```

command ls executes if I don't use exec or system.

Is there a way to execute the contents of the buffer?

Comment: Are you expecting it to run in the current shell or on the remote host?

Comment: i want 'ls' to execute in current shell

Comment: this problem bothers me a lot too; perl isn't the issue, even `ssh newhost 'sleep 3'` at the command prompt will have terminal input flushed when it exits (while just `sleep 3` will not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging i found ssh has has an stdio redirector when used with -n option.

http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/
To tell ssh that the remote command doesn't require any input use the -n option